# Bathroom outlet has poor Continuity, no tripped breakers

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just moved into a used home and replacing outlets (prior family loved pulling by the cord). In the master bedroom bath, I removed the old outlet and installed the new one. Did not short or ground fault the wires. I now have poor continuity, without breaker tripping. I noticed that the garage has no power now, and earlier I had a temporary loss of power in the garage that corrected itself.

I have checked the connections in the outlet box and switches but not light yet. They are all good. When I plug my continuity tester into the outlet it beeps. I had isolated the garage to this plug by removing the line out and lost the poor continuity signal in the garage without lighting any voltage or amp lights.

I had not yet checked the GFI in the main bath on the other side of the wall yet Just realized that is a possibility. I did not think that many rooms would be linked together for outlets in Utah. This would explain though why the outlet in the Master bed bath is not a GFI.

I am not able to return for a day or so and was wondering if someone had other ideas I could try upon my return in case it is not the GFI.

Comment: Well, unless you've reset the GFCI recently it's obviously not that. The don't reset themselves. Apparently one of your connections is faulty. There's not much we can say, looking at it though the internet wire.

Comment: "Pulling by the cord" has absolutely no effect on health of outlets, unless you think they were pulling sideways.  Even then it's unlikely.    'Temporary loss of power..correct itself'  just doesn't happen. I think you need to get someone who understands wiring to help you out.

Comment: What causes outlet failure is cheap Cheese outlets, like the one the local big box sells for 60 cents.   Another thing is using the "back stab" connections on the cheapie outlets.   The "screw-to-clamp" back connectors on better $3 receptacles are fine.

Comment: Isherwood I am on my way in a few moments to verify if the GFI was tripped. Understand what your saying about looking at it.

Carl Witthoft, yeah I am suspecting they were pulling sideways. Temporary loss of power might have "corrected" itself when I reset the GFI I found blown in what I thought was unrelated issue.

@Harper, thanks for the heads up about the outlets, they are a mediocre quality I think I will go with the screws then.

From the sounds of the replies I may have used too much information.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a loose connection somewhere.

This outlet may be the culprit, or maybe one upstream.

Since this outlet was the most recently changed, I would take off the wires and check them with a volt meter so see if you are getting consistent power to that point.

Then reinstall the outlet and see how it goes.

From that you should be able to determine the location of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I had already determined that the outlet does not have continuity. But from what you are saying. I am more confident when I get there in the next little bit, I will find the upstream GFI tripped.
Thanks.

Comment: Appreciate it. Just got back, and it was upstream. The GFI was tripped. After reseting it, the GFI tripped itself again after about five minutes.

Went downstairs to open the door, it worked. I left and came back a bit later and it was tripped again. Replaced the GFI outlet and havent had an issue since.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  As long as it is not randomly re-tripping, then whatever caused it isn't chronic.  That's always a good thing.